# Show that a $ \ 2$-adic integer not divisible by $4$ is a square

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

> Show that a $ \ 2$-adic  integer not divisible by $4$ is a square iff it is congruent to $1$ $\pmod 8 $.

---

**My try:**

We know that $a \equiv 1  \pmod 8$ implies $a$ is  a square modulo $2^n$ for all $n$.

Hence the converse part can be proved using this but how to prove the first implication?

Comment: So $a$ is congruent to one of $1,2,3,5,6,7$ modulo $8$. Which alternatives you have trouble eliminating as a square? Which can you? Or did I misunderstand what you meant with *converse*?

Answer (score 2):

If a $2$-adic integer $x$ is an odd square, say $x=y^2$, then $x\equiv y^2\pmod{8}$ and hence...

Comment: So how to prove the converse?  Problem asked for proof in both directions.

Comment: @Servaes, I did not understand your proof. Can you explain in  more details please and in both directions ?

Comment: @OscarLanzi The question only asks for the one implication.